# AttributeError: 'AccumOptimizer' object has no attribute 'lr'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I am trying to implement a code for Accumulated Gradient Optimizer in Keras.
I obtained this code from this github repo https://github.com/bojone/accum_optimizer_for_keras

```
class AccumOptimizer(Optimizer):
    def __init__(self,optimizer,steps_per_update=1,**kwargs):
        self.name=kwargs['name']
        super(AccumOptimizer,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.optimizer=optimizer
        print(self.optimizer.lr)
        #setattr(self,'lr',self.lr)
        with tf.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
            self.steps_per_update=steps_per_update
            self.iterations=tf.Variable(0,dtype='int64',name='iterations')
            self.cond=tf.equal(self.iterations%self.steps_per_update,0)
            self.lr=self.optimizer.lr
            self.optimizer.lr=tf.cond(self.cond,lambda:self.optimizer.lr.value(), lambda:0.)
            for attr in ['momentum', 'rho', 'beta_1', 'beta_2']:
                if hasattr(self.optimizer,attr):
                    value=getattr(self.optimizer,attr)
                    setattr(self, attr, value)
                    setattr(self.optimizer, attr, tf.cond(self.cond, lambda:value.value(), lambda:1 - 1e-7))
            for attr in self.optimizer.get_config():
                #print(attr)
                if not hasattr(self, attr):
                    value = getattr(self.optimizer, attr)
                    setattr(self, attr, value)
            self._create_slots=self.optimizer._create_slots
            self._resource_apply_dense=self.optimizer._resource_apply_dense
            
            def get_gradients(loss,params):
                return [ag / self.steps_per_update for ag in self.accum_grads]
            self.optimizer.get_gradients = get_gradients
    def get_updates(self,loss,params):
        self.iterations=tf.add(self.iterations, 1)
        self.optimizer.iterations=tf.add(self.optimizer.iterations, tf.cast(self.cond, 'int64'))
        self.updates=[
            self.iterations,
            self.optimizer.iterations
        ]
        # (gradient accumulation)
        self.accum_grads = [tf.zeros(p.shape,dtype=p.dtype) for p in params]
        grads = self.get_gradients(loss, params)
                                     
        for g, ag in zip(grads, self.accum_grads):
            self.updates.append(ag=tf.cond(self.cond,lambda:g,lambda:ag+g))
        
        # optimizer (inheriting updates of original optimizer)
        self.updates.extend(self.optimizer.get_updates(loss, params)[1:])
        self.weights.extend(self.optimizer.weights)
        return self.updates     
    
    def get_config(self):
        config = self.optimizer.get_config()
        return config
```

When I run this code in a cell in Jupyter Notebook, I get no error

When I compile the model

```
model.compile(optimizer=AccumOptimizer(tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate = 0.0001),16,name = 'RMSProp_Accum'), 
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
metrics=tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy())
```

I get an output from the print statement I have used `print(self.optimizer.lr)` inside the class as

`<tf.Variable 'learning_rate:0' shape=() dtype=float32, numpy=1e-04>`

But `print(self.lr)` after the line `self.lr = self.optimizer.lr` gives the error again.

When I run `model.fit()` in which I have used a `LearningRateScheduler` callback, I get this error

`AttributeError: 'AccumOptimizer' object has no attribute 'lr'`

Why am I getting this error, even though I am setting `self.lr = self.optimizer.lr`?

Also, after compiling the model, when I run `model.optimizer.lr` in a separate cell, I get the same error.

**EDIT**

I am using `tf.keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler` while training and this callback has this code

```
def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    if not hasattr(self.model.optimizer, 'lr'):
      raise ValueError('Optimizer must have a "lr" attribute.')
```

which is causing the issue.

Without using this callback, I am getting no AttributeError.

Now, to use this callback along with the `fit()` the AttributeError needs to be solved.

Comment: AFAIK, `lr` replaced with `learning_rate` - replace and re-run.

Comment: It says  `'learning_rate:0'`. I don't really know much about this topic but I think the learning rate should be `>0`.

Comment: @M.Innat I have tried changing it but it did not work. I have added something to my question ,which may help you understand why I asked this even after trying what you said.

Comment: Do you mean, you've tried by changing all `lr` to `learning_rate`, every place of your whole code - and still get the attribution error? If so, can you provide a reproducible code via colab or gist?

Comment: @M.Innat Yes, I tried that. As I have said in the "EDIT" part of the question, the main error occurs because of the callback. It looks for the attribute 'lr'. I looked into the source code on github and found out this. However, when I don't use the callback, no error occurs even without changing 'lr' to 'learning_rate'. Even when I do `print(self.lr)` just after `self.lr = self.optimizer.lr` I get the error. So, I think the problem is more pythonic than of Keras.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `lr` and `learning_rate` with the following code:

```
self._set_hyper('lr', optimizer.lr)
self._set_hyper('learning_rate', optimizer.learning_rate)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).